# Given two lists of lists find specific matches - fastest solution

Tags: python, list, loops, filter

Given two lists of lists of arbitrary length, let's say `list1` and `list2` I want to divide the lists in `list1` into subsets of lists, if they contain only one of the lists of `list2`.

I give you a specific example:

```
list1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10], 
      [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 11, 12], [1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10], [1, 2, 4, 5, 11, 12], 
      [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10], [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12], [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10], 
      [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12], [3, 4, 5, 6, 8], [3, 5, 9, 10], [3, 5, 11, 12], 
      [4, 6, 7], [4, 6, 8, 9, 10], [4, 6, 8, 11, 12], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

list2 = [[2], [6, 7], [6, 8], [9,9]]
```

and then desired outcome of the function would be for "inner" matches:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], 
[1, 2, 4, 5, 11, 12], 
[4, 6, 7], 
[3, 4, 5, 6, 8], 
[4, 6, 8, 11, 12], 
[3, 5, 9, 10], 
[9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

and for the "outer" matches (that are consequently the remaining items in `list_1`):

```
[(1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12), 
(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12), 
(4, 6, 8, 9, 10), 
(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10), 
(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8), 
(1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 11, 12), 
(1, 2, 3, 6, 7), 
(3, 5, 11, 12), 
(1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10), 
(1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10), 
(1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10)]
```

I coded a quick and dirty solution that produces the desired outcome, but does not scale well for very long lists (for example 100000 & 2500).

My solution:

```
from itertools import chain

def find_all_sets(list1,list2):
    
    d = {}
    d2 = {}
    count = 0 
    
    for i in list2:
        
        count = count + 1
        set2 = set(i)
        d['set'+str(count)] = set2
        
        d['lists'+str(count)] = []
        first = []
        
        d2['match'+str(count)]  = []
        
        for a in list1:
        
            set1 = set(a)
            if d['set'+str(count)].issubset(set1) == True:
              
                first.append(a)    
        d['lists'+str(count)].append(first)  
        d2['match'+str(count)].append(d['lists'+str(count)])
        
    count = 0 
    count2 = -1
    d3 = {}
    all_sub_lists = []
    for i in d2.values():
        
        count = count + 1
        count2 = count2 + 1
        d3['final'+str(count)]  = []
    
        real = []
        for item in i:

            for each_item in item:
                           
                for each_each_item in each_item:
                    seta= set(each_each_item)
                    save = []
                    
                    
                    for i in list2:
                    
                        setb = set(i)
                        a=setb.issubset(seta)
    
                        save.append(a)
                        
                    index_to_remove = count2
                    new_save = save[:index_to_remove] + save[index_to_remove + 1:]
                    if True not in new_save:
                        real.append(each_each_item)
                        
            d3['final'+str(count)].append(real)
            
            all_sub_lists.append(real)             
   
    inner_matches = list(chain(*all_sub_lists))
    setA = set(map(tuple, inner_matches))
    setB = set(map(tuple, list1))

    outer_matches = [i for i in setB if i not in setA]
    
    return inner_matches, outer_matches

inner_matches, outer_matches = find_all_sets(list1,list2)
```

I am looking for a **faster** way to process large lists. Please excuse if the terminology of "inner" an "outer" matches is unclear. I did not know how else to call them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion (let me know if you need it as a function):

```
inner_matches=[]
outer_matches=[]

for i in list1:
    if sum(1 for k in list2 if set(k).intersection(set(i))==set(k))==1:
        inner_matches.append(i)
    else:
        outer_matches.append(i)

print(inner_matches)
#[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5, 11, 12], [3, 4, 5, 6, 8], [3, 5, 9, 10], [4, 6, 7], [4, 6, 8, 11, 12], [9, 10, 11, 12]]

print(outer_matches)
#[[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 11, 12], [1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10], [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10], [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12], [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12], [3, 5, 11, 12], [4, 6, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well and is certainly faster and easier. I will wait a bit to see if there are more (faster) answers coming then I accept.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses `issubset()` to detect the inner lists. Using your sample data it's faster than your algorithm by a factor of nearly 4.

```
inner = []
outer = []

search_sets = [set(l) for l in list2]
for l in list1:
    if sum(s.issubset(l) for s in search_sets) == 1:
        inner.append(l)
    else:
        outer.append(l)

print(f'{inner = }')
print()
print(f'{outer = }')
```

Output

```
inner = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4, 5, 11, 12], [3, 4, 5, 6, 8], [3, 5, 9, 10], [4, 6, 7], [4, 6, 8, 11, 12], [9, 10, 11, 12]]


outer = [[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8], [1, 2, 3, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 11, 12], [1, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10], [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10], [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12], [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10], [1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12], [3, 5, 11, 12], [4, 6, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: I'd be interested to know what the down vote is for. Seems odd.

Comment: I do not understand the downvote either. You provided a solution to my question which works and is faster. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @mhawke the downvote was from me. No offence, but I consider your solution as a copy of mine, with tiny changes. And it's a problem with many paths to solve.

Comment: @IoaTzimas: yes, it's similar and although I had also independently arrived at a similar solution, you answered first. I did see yours before I posted, and it did influence my answer slightly, but it's not a copy, it is an obvious approach. I did try others such as calculating the "inner" list in a one line list comprehension and then generating the "outer" list from that, but these alternatives were slower to execute, as iis your solution which is approx twice as slow as mine due to your creation of temporary sets.....

Comment: @IoaTzimas: Thank you for your honesty and explanation. It's OK to build on each other's answers, and I have also upvoted yours on the basis that it is a useful answer, and was useful to me also.